# Common login web to redirect to separate webs

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 3 separate net core web apps on the same IIS web server. All of them are equals at 90% but every one has its own database, its own users and its own subdomain.

I would like to have a unique web app to login into the corresponding final web app depending on the user logged, basicly because I need all the users to access from a specific URL `login.my-platform.com` By now every user access through its web app with a login page on its subdomain.

```
USER        FINAL WEB APP
==================================
111         platfA.my-platform.com
222         platfA.my-platform.com
333         platfB.my-platform.com
444         platfB.my-platform.com
555         platfC.my-platform.com
```

Moreover, from a final web app, a user could create more users to that final web app, so the user will be accesible from the login web app.

I think an inappropriate solution would be to try to loggin to the 3 different databases changing the connectionString value and set a short connection timeout, but I want to avoid it. I think there must be a better solution and I just need a little bit of lighting. Thanks

Comment: You could store the user information in one separate database

Comment: Thanks @Luc. Something like use two dbcontext?

Answer (score 0):

There's two approaches:

1. Shared cookies
2. Distributed auth

The first method is available only because all of these sites share the same primary domain, i.e. `my-platform.com`. If that's not the case or it changes in the future, this won't work. You'll need to do two things: every site will need to be configured to use the same auth cookie name and domain (the wildcard `.my-platform.com`). Then, you'll need to set up a data protection provider on each that pulls from the same source. [See this article for more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x).

The second method, is more complicated, but also more robust. You'll need to utilize something like [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/) or a third-party service like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/). The former requires more code and configuration, but is free; the latter is virtually drop-in but  not free and can become quite expensive, in fact, depending on your usage. In either case, your applications will connect to this distributed auth service for both authentication and authorization. For normal user login, you'd like follow an OpenID Connect workflow, where the user will be redirected to the distributed auth website to authenticate and then will be redirected back to the originating website with a token. The originating website, then, can use this token to request the user claim, and then set a cookie in the normal way.